# Unknown state of hidden text box in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm in the process of creating a set of macros to clean up and reformat specific MS Word documents. I started by looping though the text boxes in the header of a Word document when I came across a hidden text box which I cannot find in the document though any other means.

The text box in question is not visible in the document and I cannot tell it apart from other text boxes in VBA aside from a slight position difference, content, and order in the document. I can read and write its properties and even "select" it but I can't see it in the document and can't tell it apart from other text boxes though VBA.

What I would like to do is to be able to determine what the difference is between this mystery text box and the other visible text boxes via VBA aside from the position, content, and order properties. I would like to be able to find the "hidden" text box and delete it, the problem is that I cannot determine which one is the "hidden" text box.

I created a scaled-down version of the document with only the mystery text box and one other regular text box and uploaded it [here on Dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42252515/Mystery_Text_Box.docm), it has 2 text boxes in the header and is macro-enabled with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub findTextBox()

    Dim objShapeCount As Integer
    Dim objShapes As Shapes
    Dim state As MsoTriState
    Dim i As Integer

    Set objShapes = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Shapes
    objShapeCount = objShapes.Count
    Debug.Print "Number of shapes: " + CStr(objShapeCount)

        For i = objShapeCount To 1 Step -1
        If objShapes(i).Type = msoTextBox Then
            'Texbox found
            objShapes(i).Select
            MsgBox objShapes(i).TextFrame.TextRange
            'Debug everything
            Debug.Print "Type: " + CStr(objShapes(i).Type)
            Debug.Print "Name: " + CStr(objShapes(i).Name)
            Debug.Print "Height: " + CStr(objShapes(i).Height)
            Debug.Print "Width: " + CStr(objShapes(i).Width)
            Debug.Print "Left: " + CStr(objShapes(i).Left)
            Debug.Print "Top: " + CStr(objShapes(i).Top)
            Debug.Print "Id: " + CStr(objShapes(i).ID)
            objShapes(i).Visible = 1 'C'mon! Show me!
            Debug.Print "Invisible: " + CStr(state = objShapes(i).Visible) 'Crap
            Debug.Print "Z Order: " + CStr(objShapes(i).ZOrderPosition)
            Debug.Print "Background: " + CStr(objShapes(i).BackgroundStyle)
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Can anyone find a way to tell them apart though VBA? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

After spending days trying to figure out this mess, I have come to the conclusion that this mystery text box is either an old corrupt text box or something that didn't import properly from other software.

Based on that premise, I am using the Z Order to separate any 2 text boxes that have equal properties, under the logic that the most recently-added text box (the text box with the higher Z Order) is the text box the client wants to use.

So far this has worked out, it's not fool-proof however it's all I have to go on. All documents are proofed once the macro has run so any errors should be caught.

I am still open to other suggestions but I will run with this for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally (accidentally) found the missing text box. It exists in the first page header. It can been seen by changing the page setup on the layout tab and checking "Different first page"

Even though this document didn't have first page header, text and textboxes can still exist there and are not deleted when the setup changes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a weird one. It looks like your mystery text box belongs to the first page header (which doesn't really exist in your document, except as potential).

So, to check for it, try something like:

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Shapes(2).Anchor.Information(wdHeaderFooterType)
```

I'm not sure exactly what you'll do with the information, but the mystery box has a value of 4 (or First page header) as opposed to 1 (Odd page header). See this page for a description of the possible values: http://www.rosetech.in/word_vba_category_document_informatoin.html

Note that you have the check the anchor, not the box itself (which is in a Textframe story regardless of its placement in the header).

Comment: Yes, it is a weird one. The original file has both text boxes in the first page header, I didn't update the code when I scaled down the document.

Comment: So you get the same value for the .anchor.information(wdHeaderFooterType) for both boxes?

Comment: Apologies, in the original file both text boxes were in the first page header and had a value of 4. I must have changed the location of the text box when I created the example. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Word 2007 so can't look at it in Word. But 2007 files are zip files. So rename the file to zip and open it as a folder. In Header2.xml and header3.xml there is a shape called MysteryTextBox, and it's binary data. Just make a backup and delete the xml.

See here if you want to decode it. http://officeopenxml.com/drwShape.php

Comment: Thank you, however I am tying to automate the process though VBA and distribute it for others to use. That text box could be called anything when I receive the document and I need a way to tell apart the visible box from the hidden one in VBA. It has given me the idea to redline the 2 XML files for property differences so I will try that.

Comment: Put up a RTF format of the doc. I have some RTF knowledge and tools (but Word's RTF is mostly gibberish). As RTF it can be loaded in a richtext box and accessed via Text Object Model (TOM) via the Window or through the a Rich Text Box's object model.

Comment: [Here is an RTF version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2z8temdycdyoatp/Mystery_Text_Box.rtf?dl=0) of the file via Dropbox. Thanks.